# Rails Fetching group_id From Another Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In the User model, I have an archive! method that is called when a User is destroyed.

A User has many User Groups which should be stored in a new ArchivedUserGroup table when a User is destroyed.

The ArchivedUser is successfully created, but I am having trouble fetching the Users' `group_id` from the UserGroup table.

```
      ArchivedUserGroup.create(
        user_id: self.id, 
        group_id: UserGroup.where(:user_id => self.id).pluck(:group_id).to_set
      )
```

Thanks for anyone that has helped me, I am just getting started with Rails and working with a rather complex codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are many UserGroup records for each user and an ArchivedUserGroup has the same attributes as a regular UserGroup (user_id, group_id), I think you should be created an ArchivedUserGroup for each of the users UserGroup records and not just one. You're trying to pass a set (like an array) to the group_id column. Although you haven't shown your schema, probably group_id is an integer since it's a foreign key, so there's a data type mismatch. Instead you could do this:

```
UserGroup.where(user_id: self.id).each do |user_group|
  ArchivedUserGroup.create(
    user_id: self.id,
    group_id: user_group.group_id
  )
end
```

In case some users have a large number of user groups, this may be slow because there's a DB call (create) happening in an iteration. This is known as an N+1 query and the way around it in this case would be to use a bulk insert, either via raw SQL or something like the `bulk_insert` gem.

Comment: I was thinking of looping through UserGroup where the user_id was equal to self.id...not sure why I didn't try this sooner. Thanks a lot for your description; do you have any recommended readings that I should check out that would cover something similar to this?

Comment: @VegaStudios The Rails guide on ActiveRecord is a start.